# Realtime Tracking using leaflet

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, leaflet, tracking

I was wondering I can Realtime Tracking my location with leaflet using Ionic ,I was able to get my current location, but I also want to keep track of it when I move

```
 this.map.locate({
  setView: true,
  maxZoom: 16
}).on('locationfound', (e) => {
  let markerGroup = leaflet.featureGroup();
  this.marker = leaflet.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude], { icon: carIcon }).addTo(this.map);
```

Answer (score 7):

[`locate`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#locate-options) accepts a `watch` option that will let you continuously update your marker position:

> **watch**     Type: Boolean   Default: false
> If true, starts continuous watching of location changes (instead of detecting it once) using W3C `watchPosition` method. You can later stop watching using `map.stopLocate()` method.

For example:

```js
this.map.locate({
    watch: true,
    setView: true,
    maxZoom: 16
}).on('locationfound', (e) => {
    if (!this.marker) {
        this.marker = leaflet.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude], { icon: carIcon }).addTo(this.map);
    } else {
        this.marker.setLatLng([e.latitude, e.longitude]);
    }
}
```